# How to connect Java and MySQL on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu-drivers

I can see some exception like this. Please help me.

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

This is the program I am trying to execute to establish connection.

```java
    import java.sql.*;

    class Connect
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
        {
        try{
            String dbUrl="jdbc.mysql://localhost:3306/EMPLOYEE";
            String username="root";
            String password="avinash";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection myconnection=DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl,username,password);
            Statement mystatement=myconnection.createStatement();
            ResultSet myresultset=mystatement.executeQuery("select * from EMPLOYEE");
        }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. The first error was here. I typed `jdbc.mysql://localhost:3306/EMPLOYEE` instead of `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EMPLOYEE`. That is, *a dot(.)* instead of a *colon(:)* after jdbc in the above statement. After correcting this I got another error saying:

> Thu Mar 28 15:38:38 IST 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.

Then I set `?useSSL=false` in the statement `String dbUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EMPLOYEE?useSSL=false";` Then I successfully managed to execute the program.

Java:

```java
import java.sql. * ;

class Connect {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EMPLOYEE?useSSL=false";
            String username = "root";
            String password = "avinash";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection myconnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, username, password);
            Statement mystatement = myconnection.createStatement();
            ResultSet myresultset = mystatement.executeQuery("select * from EMPLOYEES");
            System.out.println("Connected");
            while (myresultset.next()) {
                System.out.println("Employee ID : " + myresultset.getString("ID"));
                System.out.println("Employee Age : " + myresultset.getString("AGE"));
                System.out.println("Employee Name : " + myresultset.getString("FIRST_NAME") + " " + myresultset.getString("LAST_NAME"));
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

...with the output...

```
$ javac Connect.java
$ java -cp .:mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar Connect
Connected
Employee ID : 100
Employee Age : 18
Employee Name : zaara ali
Employee ID : 101
Employee Age : 20
Employee Name : manam naman
Employee ID : 102
Employee Age : 22
Employee Name : zaid khan
Employee ID : 103
Employee Age : 24
Employee Name : sumith das
```

but have doubts. Why should this program be run like this, using this command?

```
java -cp .:mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar Connect
```

Please help:)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the mysql connector to your project.

There are plenty of ways and tools to do it, I suggest you one here.

The connector can be downloaded on [mysql website](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). Choose the "Platform independant" to get an archive that will contain a JAR file.

Then extract the downloaded archive and move the JAR file with your project source.

Then adding it to your project can be done with your IDE. For example, this is the procedure to follow with Eclipse (2018-09 - More details on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30213822/how-to-add-mysql-jar-to-java-desktop-application-in-jdeveloper)):

1. In project explorer, right click on your project
2. Select Properties
3. In the Properties window, click on "Java Build Path" in the left panel
4. In the Java Build Path, click on "Librairies" tab
5. Select Classpath and use the button "Add JARs" on the right

[image: java build path screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much. Error was with the code. I typed . instead of a : in the url field. And after setting "?useSSL=false" only i got the output. And about the IDE i did not know until I read whatever you shared. Thanks for your time:) Thanks FloT...